# Custom Route Redirecting in Rails from /users/username to /username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes

I have a path as below
http://localhost:3000/users/username

---

views

```
<%= link_to user.title, user %>
```

---

route.rb

```
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", signout: "logout"}, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/company'
  end
  resources :users, only: [:show, :destroy]
  get '/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :profile
  get '/users/:id', to: redirect('/%{id}')
```

---

when I type http://localhost:3000/username it works fine, but all my links from link_to user.title, user goes to http://localhost:3000/users/username.

**How can I force link_to to go http://localhost:3000/username**?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the route you are redirecting from located in the routes.rb file?  Above the redirect?

Comment: Can you run `rails routes | grep users` and edit your question with the results?